Refactoring DB::raw() to DB::raw()->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar()) in Laravel 10
i migrate from Laravel 8 to Laravel 10 so i used in whole project DB::raw(). in laravel 10, DB::raw() does not work must use DB::raw()->getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar())
how can i refactor this in all of my project about 35 files and 135 usage in my project
i used this package but have an error : https://github.com/remarkablemark/rector-laravel-database-expressions

How are you using DB::raw to actually encounter this issue? You would not normally need to get the raw expression as a string, you can just plug DB::raw in any query builder query.

yea but DB:raw since laravel 10 not returend string it's return object

If you use code like DB::table('x')->where('y', DB::raw('anything')) this code works in Laravel 10+ in the exact same way it worked in Laravel 8. If you were relying on getting strings from DB::raw then I think you were doing something you should not have

Can you show examples of your code where this is an issue?

yea i refactor that just where i use ->whereRaw i get error or HavingRaw
